# Python Requests post error response in chat system

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to chat and send a photo on a system by python automatically. but give me the following error. Can you show me how to fix it?
the way I do is by Python Requests post () Method

imformation for files Request URL

```
Request URL: https://11.chat.com/file-api/v2/teams/123/rooms/123/attachment/files
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 11.111.11.11:11
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-expose-headers: Accept-Ranges,Content-Encoding,Content-Length,Content-Range
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Mon, 11 Apr 2020 1:36:05 GMT
chat-correlationid: 123-a0c0-11eb-ba75-bbcbc762f736
server: nginx/1.19.0 (Ubuntu)
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-powered-by: Express
:authority: 11.chat.com
:method: POST
:path: /file-api/v2/teams/123/rooms/123/attachment/files
:scheme: https
accept: application/vnd.tosslab.chat-v2+json
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: ja,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.7
authorization: bearer c12a8c2c975a23f73141320f6ad0fab108a6c03e1620fcb71772e5212b1aab745e32791d1b50bc2cb9ae6197e4f1d012
content-length: 103
content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
origin: https://www.chat.com
referer: https://www.chat.com/
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36
x-account-id: 121c7942-b51d-4fba-932a-74f3df74b215
x-member-id: 1234
x-team-id: 1234
{fileName: "16188033640933e8796c2644e41653c1d0a6286c79c7c", title: "screenshot.jpeg"}
fileName: "16188033640933e8796c2644e41653c1d0a6286c79c7c"
title: "screenshot.jpeg"
```

imformation for POST Request URL

```
Request URL: https://11.chat.com/message-api/v1/teams/1234/rooms/1234/posts
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 11.111.11.11:111
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-expose-headers: Accept-Ranges,Content-Encoding,Content-Length,Content-Range
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Mon, 11 Apr 2020 01:36:07 GMT
chat-correlationid: 600509c0-a0c0-11eb-8717-a38bfaeb5981
server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-powered-by: Express
:authority: 11.chat.com
:method: POST
:path: /message-api/v1/teams/1234/rooms/1234/posts
:scheme: https
accept: application/vnd.tosslab.chat-v2+json
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: ja,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.7
authorization: bearer c122a8c2c975a23f73141320f6ad0fab108a6c03e1620fcb71772e520b1aab745e32791d1b50bc2cb9a1237e4f1d07f6
content-length: 56
content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
origin: https://www.chat.com
referer: https://www.chat.com/
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36
x-account-id: 121c7942-b51d-4fba-932a-74f3df74b215
x-member-id: 1234
x-team-id: 1234
{title: "TEST", content: "test", fileIds: [1234]}
content: "test"
fileIds: [1234]
title: "TEST"
```

imformation for files Request Response

```
{"id":111,"fromEntity":1234,"teamId":1234,"info":{"inviteUsers":[],"createInfo":{"members":[],"pg_members":[],"ch_members":[]}},"pollId":null,"feedbackType":null,"feedbackId":-1,"status":"created","messageId":1483745833,"time":1618803367054,"toEntity":[17274139],"message":{"id":1483745833,"teamId":13481330,"writerId":13489639,"contentType":"post","permission":740,"updatedAt":"2021-04-19T03:36:07.049Z","createdAt":"2021-04-19T03:36:07.049Z","isThreaded":false,"isEdited":false,"sharedMessages":[],"attachments":[{"content":{"connectInfo":[],"extraInfo":{"thumbnailUrl":"https://chat-box.com/files-thumb/13481330/16188033640933e8796c2644e41653c1d0a6286c79c7c","smallThumbnailUrl":"https://chat-box.com/files-thumb/13481330/16188033640933e8796c2644e41653c1d0a6286c79c7c?size=80","mediumThumbnailUrl":"https://chat-box.com/files-thumb/13481330/16188033640933e8796c2644e41653c1d0a6286c79c7c?size=320","largeThumbnailUrl":"https://chat-box.com/files-thumb/13481330/16188033640933e8796c2644e41653c1d0a6286c79c7c?size=640","width":985,"height":589},"todo":{},"drive":{},"filterType":"image","externalShared":false,"externalUrl":null,"externalCode":null,"fileUrl":"https://files.chat.com/files-private/1234/16188033640933e8796c2644e41653c1d0a6286c79c7c","serverUrl":"s3","ext":"jpeg","size":235967,"icon":"image","type":"image/jpeg","filename":"16188033640933e8796c2644e41653c1d0a6286c79c7c","name":"screenshot.jpeg","title":"screenshot.jpeg"},"contentType":"file","id":1111}],"mentions":[],"info":{"mention":[]},"likedCount":0,"commentCount":0,"formatKey":null,"isFormatted":false,"todoId":null,"postId":null,"pollId":null,"feedbackId":-1,"shareEntities":[1234],"status":"created","linkPreviewId":null,"content":{"title":"TEST","body":"test","connectInfo":[]},"updateTime":1618803367049,"createTime":1618803367049,"deleterId":null,"from":"web"}}
```

code

```
import urllib.request, json
import requests
import mimetypes
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder
from datetime import datetime as dt

#Header information
LOGIN_API_ENDPOINT  = "https://11.chat.com/inner-api/token"

BOARD_POST_API_ENDPOINT = "https://11.chat.com/message-api/11/teams/{0}/rooms/{1}/posts"
BOARD_POST_FILE_UPLOAD_API_ENDPOINT = "https://upload.chat.com/file-api/11/teams/{0}/rooms/{1}/attachment/files"

BOARD_POST_COMMENT_ENDPOINT = "https://11.chat.com/-api/11/teams/{0}/posts/{1}/comments"

BOARD_GET_SEARCH_ENDPOINT = "https://11.chat.com/api/teams/{0}/search"

ROOM_ID = "12345"

#login information

login = {"username":"123",
        "password":"123",
        "platform":"web",
        "grant_type":"password"}

url = LOGIN_API_ENDPOINT
method = "POST"
headers = {"Content-Type" : "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
           "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36",
           "Origin": "https://www.chat.com",
           "Accept": "application/vnd.tosslab.chat-v4+json"}

# DateTime
strDate = dt.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
strTime = dt.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")

#Python for Json change 
login_data = login
token_obj = {}
json_data = json.dumps(login_data).encode("utf-8")

# login
# http for POST
request = urllib.request.Request(url, data=json_data, method=method, headers=headers)
with urllib.request.urlopen(request) as response:
    token_obj = json.loads(response.read().decode("utf-8"))
    print(token_obj)
    print(token_obj["token_type"])
    print(token_obj["access_token"])

# chat server file upload
url = BOARD_POST_FILE_UPLOAD_API_ENDPOINT.format(TEAM_ID,ROOM_ID)
# --------------------------------------------1-------------------

#MIMETYPE change file
fileName = 'C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\screenshot.jpeg'
XLSX_MIMETYPE = mimetypes.guess_type(fileName)[0]

print(XLSX_MIMETYPE)

fileDataBinary = open(fileName, 'rb')
files = {'file': ('screenshot.jpeg', fileDataBinary, XLSX_MIMETYPE)}

#Uploading Data 
m = MultipartEncoder(
    fields={'title': 'screenshot.jpeg', 
            'file': ('screenshot.jpeg', fileDataBinary, XLSX_MIMETYPE)}
    )
auth = "{0} {1}".format(token_obj["token_type"], token_obj["access_token"])
headers = {'Content-Type' : m.content_type, 'Authorization' : auth}
response = requests.post(url,data=m,headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.content)
return_file_data = json.loads(response.content)


auth = "{0} {1}".format(token_obj["token_type"], token_obj["access_token"])

#Post chat
url = BOARD_POST_API_ENDPOINT.format(TEAM_ID,ROOM_ID)
print(url)
# print(return_file_data["id"])
fileList = []
fileList.append(return_file_data["id"])
payload = {"title":"test",
        "content":"hello python world",
        "fileIds":fileList}
title: "TEST"
print(payload)
headers1 = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Authorization' : auth}
print(headers1)
response = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(payload).encode("utf-8"),headers=headers1)
```

error

```
{'access_token': '12396dae54be29417882f5c5d72822121aa5a0', 'expires_in': 43200, 'refresh_token': '123139ec591043f23046f3b4b512134b5db4f7a445212550b6de60', 'token_type': 'bearer', 'ts': 1618805067661}
bearer
12396dae54be29417882f5c5d72822121aa5a0
image/jpeg
503
b''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/test/Documents/test/test_post.py", line 78, in <module>
    return_file_data = json.loads(response.content)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
PS C:\Users\test>
```

If anyone knows, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

As per the error logs it seems you are getting empty data in response.

Status 503 means there might be error in API, so the response is empty.

You can directly use `resp.json()` method instead of `json.dump(resp.content)`

```
return_file_data = response.json()
```

Also add check for `response.status_code == 200` and then take content from the response.

Comment: thanks for the answer i changed it like you told me
but I got the same error `raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: `response.status_code == 200`
How do I check if the code is 200?
Excuse me, I'm not covered in this

Comment: `if response.status_code == 200:` then proceed to next logic. else abort function